# Bigcommerce Stencil show catalog on home page

Tags: bigcommerce

I am working with the Stencil theme "Cornerstone" to develop a custom storefront and I am wanting the home page view (home.html) to display my product catalog much like a category page does - example from the Cornerstone Warm demo [Here](http://cornerstone-warm-demo.mybigcommerce.com/all-coffee/).

I see the carousel that displays: products.new, products.featured, and products.top_sellers, however when I try and loop through just products I don't get anything returned.

Is there a front-matter expression that I need in order to show products on the home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a front matter expression that will call all products or call products from a specific category. It would be easier to set a high number of new or featured products and use that to populate your home page.

The caveat is that the number of products you choose to show can have a negative impact on the load time and user experience so if you go this route, I'd lazyload product in increments.

Comment: Is there a way to set my home page to a category page? I know you can set  your home page to content page.

Comment: There isn't. You could redirect from the home page to the /products/ page but that might be a negative customer experience.